# The value of $\lim_{m \to \infty} \ (-m)!$

Tags: gamma-function, integers, infinite-product

If we know that
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} (-m+\frac 1 2) =0$$ 
when $m \in \Bbb z$

Can we say that:$$(-\infty)!=0$$

Actually by looking to the graph of gamma function the curve tends to infinity for the negative integers.

But what happen if $m \rightarrow \infty$ and $m \in \Bbb Z$ for:

$$\lim_{m \to -\infty} (-m)!$$

I was thinking it will be the same , but the following steps gave me zero value for it, as below.

First we have fact $$\lim_{m \to \infty} (\frac 1 m)!=1$$

The limit can be written as 
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} (\frac 1 m-1)!\frac 1 m =1$$

by repeating the process we get 
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} ](\frac 1 m-m-1)! \left [ \frac 1 m \, (\frac 1 m-1)(\frac 1 m-2)...(\frac 1 m-m) \right ]=1$$

Now we have

$$ \lim_{m \to \infty}(\frac 1 m-1)(\frac 1 m-2)...(\frac 1 m-m)= \lim_{m \to \infty}(-1)^m(\frac 1 m+m)!$$

by substitute it in the equation.

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} (\frac 1 m-m-1)! \left [\frac 1 m \,(-1)^m(\frac 1 m+m)!\right ] =1$$

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}(\frac 1 m-m-1)!=\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac m {(-1)^m(\frac 1 m+m)!}$$

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}(\frac 1 m-m-1)!=\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac {(\frac 1 m +m)-\frac 1 m} {(-1)^m(\frac 1 m+m)!}$$

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}(\frac 1 m-m-1)!=\lim_{m \to \infty} \left [\frac {1} {(-1)^m(\frac 1 m+m-1)!}-\frac {1} {(-1)^m(\frac 1 m+m)!\,m}\right ]$$

> $$(-\infty)!=0$$

So is that true?... actually I don't know.

Comment: What is the definition of factorial in the field $\mathbb{Q}$? I ask this because $1/m - 1$ is not an integer.

Comment: On what ground does the first limit hold?

Comment: Some regularisations technique say that $+\infty ! = 2\pi$ so everything's possible in this world!

Comment: It's anyway TOTALLY UNCLEAR what you mean with

$$m\to \infty ~~~~~ m\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: @rbbau No meaning. The factorial is defined only for natural numbers. If you want to "extend" the concept, use the Gamma Function, but ti wouldn't be the factorial anymore.

Comment: Ok I will replace the factorial with gamma function, but this is not the aim of the question, the answer I need is what is $\Gamma (-\infty)$ equal to?

Comment: @FourierTransform I mean $m$ is always integer.

Comment: @Pentapolis No. If you use the Gamma, then $m$ can be whatever you want. But it happens to be the factorial if and only if $m$ is a natural number. If you take integers (understood as negative naturals) then you will always have

$$\Gamma(m) = +\infty ~~~~~ \text{for}\ m \in\mathbb{Z^-}$$

Answer (score 1):

The question is simple.

The statement

$$n! = n\cdot (n-1)!$$

only holds when $n\in\mathbb{N}$

In your case you have not a natural number a priori (you considered indeed integers, and factorial is not defined for negative naturals), since for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, the quantity $\frac{1}{m} \notin \mathbb{Z}$ so you cannot write

$$\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)! = \frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{1}{m} -1 \right)!$$

**$\Gamma[-\infty]$**

By the definition:

$$\Gamma[x] = \int_0^{+\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-t}\ \text{d}t$$

But what we have is

$$\Gamma[-\infty] = \text{Indeterminate}$$

Comment: Ok I will replace the factorial with gamma function, but this is not the aim of the question, the answer I need is what is $\Gamma(-\infty)$ equal to?

Comment: @Pentapolis It's indeterminate. You may try to make some regularisations if you want to have fun, like the one I wrote above ($+\infty ! = 2\pi$). But it doesn't have meaning.